# How do Facebook group privacy affect facebook api scraping?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm learning to use the Facebook Graph API to scrape data from facebook pages and display them in a json format using python2.7 .

I'm curious to know how the Facebook group's privacy settings will affect the data I'm able to scrape from the website. I found that scraping is limited to groups I am a member of and other groups don't return any data.

Note : I'm working with Facebook API v2.0 so I can use `user_groups` permission to access data about all my groups(not just the groups where I am the admin).

Comment: You will only be able to use user_groups permission for like 15 more days

Comment: @WizKid could you give me more details? I'm using user_groups with v2.2 in the Graph API explorer to estimate what values I can get from the api. What I know is that user_groups permission was removed for v2.5 and above.

Comment: user_groups is listed under: "90-day deprecations (effective Tuesday, October 6, 2015)" at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog